# iSQL Plus: print to screen

Tags: oracle, plsql, database, isql

How do you enable iSQL*Plus terminal to print output to screen?

For instance a simple hello world block:

[image: iSQL plus terminal]

Note how "hello world" should be printed to screen, but only confirmation that there were no compilation errors is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need enable dbms outout and set server output on.

```
exec dbms_output.enable(1000000);
```

and on top of your program paste this:

```
set serveroutput on
```

Comment: Thank you. Why Oracle documentation did not seem to mention this is beyond me (or why it isn't enabled by default).

Comment: can't really say why it is not enabled by default.

Comment: you are able to see output now?